# Find unique elements of column with chunksize pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a sample(!) data frame:

```
test = 

time  clock
1     1
1     1
2     2
2     2
3     3
3     3
```

---

I was trying to do some operations with pandas chunksize:

```
for df in pd.read_csv("...path...",chunksize = 10):
    time_spam = df.time.unique()
    detector_list = df.clock.unique()
```

---

But it gives me operation to the length of the chunsize. If 10, then give me 10 rows only.

P.S. It is sample data

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand the point of the question, what are you expecting as output?

Comment: unique values of column `time` and `clock`

Comment: What is the rationale for chunking the df? Not enough memory?

Comment: yes guys, As I wrote - sample data. Real data has 90 million rows :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
for df in pd.read_csv("...path...",chunksize = 10, iterator=True):
    time_spam = df.time.unique()
    detector_list = df.clock.unique()
```

You need to use the `iterator` flag as described here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-chunking

Comment: let me check speed

Comment: This depends on your chunk size

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can create lists of unique elements parsing chunks:

```
# Initialize lists
time_spam = []
detector_list = []

# Cycle over each chunk
for df in pd.read_csv("...path...", chunksize = 10):

    # Add elements if not already in the list
    time_spam += [t for t in df['time'].unique() if t not in time_spam] 
    detector_list += [c for c in df['clock'].unique() if c not in detector_list ]
```

Comment: let me check speed

Comment: A faster alternative could be to add them in a single list, then use `list(set(...))`

Answer (score 0):

File `test.csv`:

```
col1,col2
1,1
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,1
2,2
2,3
2,4
```

Code:

```
col1, col2 = [], []
for df in pd.read_csv('test.csv', chunksize = 3):
    col1.append(df.col1)
    col2.append(df.col2)
```

Results:

```
print(pd.concat(col1).unique())
```

[1 2]

```
print(pd.concat(col2).unique())
```

[1 2 3 4]